# How do I do the following recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion, nodes

Ok, so I have a regular Node list, with members info and next.

I need to use a function, recursively, to calculate the average, and then compare if each node is bigger than the average or not.

```
int Acount(NodeType* Node, int sum, int& avg){

    if (Node == NULL){//last call
        avg = sum / avg;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg) + (Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0));
        }
}
```

Which is quite simple. Problem is the value returned is always 0.
The problem appears to be with

```
(Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0));
```

I've done the tests and when I do the following:

```
return (Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg) + Node->info;
```

or

```
return (Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg) + avg;
```

Results meet expectations. As in, I'm getting the sum of the Node->info in the first case, and I'm getting average*number of nodes in the second case.

Point of this, I've proved that the function is working perfectly.

Yet when it comes to

```
(Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0));
```

Appears to be problematic, which is quite peculiar. if I place for example:

```
(Node->info == 5 ? 1 : 0));
```

And there is only one 5 in the nodes, then the function returns 1. So everything is working as intended, yet I keep getting a 0.

The following are the main functions and additional functions for the Node.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
struct NodeType{
    int info;
    NodeType *next;
};
//pre: first node passed is not NULL
int Acount(NodeType* Node, int sum, int& avg){

    if (Node == NULL){//last call
        avg = sum / avg;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg) + (Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0));
        }
}
void fill(NodeType*& Node){

    NodeType *temp;
    Node = new NodeType;
    Node->info = 0;
    Node->next = NULL;
    temp = Node;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        temp->next = new NodeType;
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->info = i;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}
void print(NodeType* Node){
    NodeType *temp = Node;
    while (temp != NULL){
        cout << temp->info << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void Delete(NodeType* Node){
    NodeType *temp;
    while (Node != NULL){
        temp = Node;
        Node = Node->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
void main(){

    int sum = 0, avg = 0;
    NodeType *Node;
    fill(Node);
    print(Node);

    cout << Acount(Node, sum, avg) << endl;

    Delete(Node);


}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can do both of these task at the same time, recursively or not.  You need the average of the entire tree before you can compare each node to it.

Comment: But I already have. I did acquire the average and I did test that after I reached the last recursive call (the NULL) all recursive calls started going back with the average as calculated.

Comment: Are you supposed to be doing something other than return 0 when Node == NULL? You calculate the avg value, but you don't do anything with it

Comment: I'm returning it the average by reference. I'm returning 0 to begin the count of all items larger than average.

Comment: See my answer and others below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ there is no concept of left-to-right (or right-to-left) evaluation order of expressions. Operator priorities will control associativity, but in the case of `f1() + f2()` there is no guarantee that `f1()` is invoked before `f2()` (and viceversa). It may depend on the compiler or other.

My suggestion is to split the expression into 2 distinct statements as follows:

```
int tmp = Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg);
return tmp + (Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Doesn't look as pretty or very recursive-ish but appears to be the only solution. Thanks.

Comment: if the issue is staying in 1 line (to make it look more functional :)), then you can try `,` operator (given you have tmp defined):
`return tmp = (Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg), tmp + (Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0))`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your code has defined behaviour. But, this line

```
return (Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg) + (Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0));
```

depends on if the left summand or the right summand is calculated first.

If it is the left one, then `Acount` goes down the recursion an incrementing `avg` until `avg` equals the number of elements in the list (here 10 when starting from zero called by the `main` routine). Note, that `avg` is passed by reference. Thus, when the recursion goes back up, this term in the right summand

```
Node->info > avg
```

will never be true because `Node->info` is set in the `fill` routine to values smaller then the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your method will work.

In this statement:

```
return (Acount(Node->next, sum + Node->info, ++avg) + (Node->info > avg ? 1 : 0))
```

You don't know when the second term has be evaluated.  It's not defined in C++.